# Xcode 4.2/Restkit cannot find interface declaration for 'NSManagedObject', did you mean 'NSManagedObjectModel'?

Tags: xcode, xcode4.2, restkit

i've created a new xcode/ios project from scratch to check some issues with Restkit:

Xcode 4.2, Restkit (https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit, Nov 09/2011)

i've configured restkit with the help of these guides:

- https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit
- https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-RestKit-in-Xcode-4.x
- liebke.github.com/restkit-github-client-example/
- mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/restkit_ios-sdk/
- checked also groups.google.com/group/restkit/

I've added the paths to the header and libraries, the compilers flags, set the target, linked together the required libraries and still when i add:

```
#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>
#import <RestKit/CoreData/CoreData.h>


in "NSManagedObject+ActiveRecord.h" i get Semantic and Parsing issues:
```

Cannot find interface declaration for 'NSManagedObject'; did you mean 'NSManagedObjectModel'?

```
CoreData.framework is included in the libraries. Any ideas?
```

thanks !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is CoreData.h, try to remove the Reskit imports and import

```
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
```

if you get the same error the solution is here:

http://groups.google.com/group/restkit/browse_thread/thread/91c36439c03f6e23

:)